# If I use "position:fixed;" can I have the position be on the right?

Tags: html, css, position, fixed

When using "position:fixed;" in my stylesheet, can I have the position also be on the right? Here's my code:

**CSS**

```
.buttons {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    text-align: right;
    position:fixed;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="main">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="buttons">
                <button class="nav-toggler toggle-slide-left">Menu</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Haven't you tried it?

Comment: Are you asking permission?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you just need to add 'right: 0;' to your .buttons CSS class.

Comment: You're welcome. See here for further information on the CSS 'position' property - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position. Also, please approve the answer so that the question is no longer categorized as unanswered.

Answer (score 1):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sachindivakar/muf1htjk/)

```
<div id="main">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="buttons">
                <button class="nav-toggler toggle-slide-left">Menu</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
.buttons {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    text-align: right;
    position:fixed;
    right:0px;//add this
}
```